# SMS Spoofing not available in kali

Tags: kali-linux, spoofing, sms

Has the SMS Spoofing option been removed from the Social Engineering Toolkit ? I run 3.14-kali1-amd64. I get only the options shown below. Tried updating both kali and SET but i  still dont get the option. Is there a separate package i can i use for it ?

Select from the menu:

- Spear-Phishing Attack Vectors
- Website Attack Vectors
- Infectious Media Generator
- Create a Payload and Listener
- Mass Mailer Attack
- Arduino-Based Attack Vector
- Wireless Access Point Attack Vector
- QRCode Generator Attack Vector
- Powershell Attack Vectors
- Third Party Modules
- Return back to the main menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/trustedsec/social-engineer-toolkit/blob/9868a7cae04c1253143e50f7b1243f6084954866/src/core/menu/text.py) is the current state of the menu definitions from their GitHub repo. It looks like the SMS module was disabled May 30th, 2014 in [this](https://github.com/trustedsec/social-engineer-toolkit/commit/ca6cd222b94c7d0c021678910f1df609434ab3ed) commit. No explanation of why. You could file an issue on their GitHub and ask.